# An array of pointer which is converted as pointer to pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

In this source code,

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(char *a[]);

int main(void)
{
        char *k[] = {"123", "4567", "89101112"};

        test(k);
}

void test(char *a[])
{
        ++a;
        ++a[0];
        a[1] += 4;

        printf("%s\n", a[-1]);
        printf("%s\n", a[0]);
        printf("%s\n", a[1]);
}
```

Output

```
123
567
1112
```

I understand `++a;` but `++a[0]` and `a[1] += 4;` seems awkward. The single object `a` remembers three properties and the result is printed as above. What is the reason for this?

Comment: What result did you  expect?

Comment: @klutt I expected the same result as shown, but I've never seen an explanation about this. I thought I had to declare two additional variables to do `++a[0];` and `a[1] += 4;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter `a` is a pointer to the array `k` which is an array of pointers to characters (`char*`). Each pointer is initialised to point to the start of the strings.

So:

```
a = k = &k[0]

a[0] = "123"
a[1] = "4567"
a[2] = "89101112"
```

Here is what happens:

```
a++
```

The pointer `a` is advanced one position, so `a` now points to `k[1]`.

```
++a[0]
```

We take the pointer at `a[0]` (which is `k[1]`) and advance it one position. So `k[1]` now points to the "5" and not "4".

```
a[1] += 4
```

We take the pointer at `a[1]` (which is `k[2]`) and advance it four positions. So `k[2]` now points to the second "1".

```
printf("%s\n", a[-1]);
printf("%s\n", a[0]);
printf("%s\n", a[1]);
```

Since we advanced `a`, then `a[-1]` points to `k[0]`, `a[0]` to `k[1]`, `a[1]` to `k[2]`. We print out the new values of the `k` array modified as described above.

Comment: Did you mean == instead of ++

Answer (score 1):

In addition to rghomes answer, I'd like to add a version with additional printouts that shows pretty clear what's going on.

```
void test(char *a[])
{
        // Before advancing the pointer, we cannot print a[-1] 
        // printf("%s\n", a[-1]);
        printf("%s\n", a[0]);
        printf("%s\n\n", a[1]);

        ++a;

        printf("%s\n", a[-1]);
        printf("%s\n", a[0]);
        printf("%s\n\n", a[1]);

    
        ++a[0];

        printf("%s\n", a[-1]);
        printf("%s\n", a[0]);
        printf("%s\n\n", a[1]);

        a[1] += 4;

        printf("%s\n", a[-1]);
        printf("%s\n", a[0]);
        printf("%s\n", a[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out
123
4567

123
4567
89101112

123
567
89101112

123
567
1112
```